# json keys replacement with overrides part

Tags: node.js

I have a configuration json file, here is a sample

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "producer": {
    "name": "app_name_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_producer",
    "kms_key_alias": "alias/app_name_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_producer_key",
    "shards": 1,
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "name": "app_name1_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_consumer",
        "account_id": "123456789012",
        "active": true
      },
      {
        "name": "app_name2_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_consumer",
        "account_id": "987654321098",
        "active": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "consumers": [
    {
      "name": "app_name_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_consumer",
      "kms_key_alias": "alias/app_name_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_consumer_key",
      "shards": 1
    }
  ],
  "overrides": {
    "prod": {
      "producer": {
        "shards": 2,
        "subscriptions": [
          {
            "name": "app_name1_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_consumer",
            "account_id": "123456789012",
            "active": false
          }
        ]
      },
      "consumers": [
        {
          "name": "app_name_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_consumer",
          "shards": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

My target is to generate a final configuration for that environment. Environment is a variable.

The configuration for `prod` will be different. Such as `producer.shards` in prod will be 2, not 1.

The process is, read the json file, part of `producer` and `consumers`, save to a new variable `new_json`. This can be understood as default values.

```
{
  "producer": {
     ...
  }
  consumers": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Then read the session of overrides, if the environment is `prod`, it will override the value in related keys.

I wrote the `forEach` codes to read each key in `overrides`, then I need confirm the key is list or map, then go the end of the part, replace the same key in `new_json`.

```
const json = JSON.parse(template)

if ({}.hasOwnProperty.call(overrides, environment)) {
  const env = overrides[environment];

  Object.keys(env).forEach((key){
      ...
  }
}
```

The sample json is a simple one. The real json has several hundred lines. So go through each key is not efficient method.

Are there any quick/smart ways to overrides any keys in overrides to `new_json` directly?

### Update #1

With [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), I still need go though each key, otherwise, I got less keys.

For example, with below code, I got less in list of `subscriptions`.

```
$ cat a.js
const fs = require('fs');
const swig = require('swig-templates');

const environment='prod';

let template = swig.compileFile("jsoncontent.json");

template = template({
  ENVIRONMENT: environment,
});

const json = JSON.parse(template);

Object.assign(json.producer, json.overrides.prod.producer)
delete json.overrides

console.log(JSON.stringify(json, null, 2));

$ node a.js
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "producer": {
    "name": "app_name_prod_producer",
    "kms_key_alias": "alias/app_name_prod_producer_key",
    "shards": 2,
    "subscriptions": [
      {
        "name": "app_name1_prod_consumer",
        "account_id": "123456789012",
        "active": false
      }
    ]
  },
  "consumers": [
    {
      "name": "app_name_prod_consumer",
      "kms_key_alias": "alias/app_name_prod_consumer_key",
      "shards": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

### Update #2

Thanks to point me to [lodash.defaultsDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#defaultsDeep), but when merge the maps in list, it has to be one to one matched in same position.

Use the exist as sample, if I adjust `overrides` a little bit, the subscriptions' first list, name is changed from `app_name1` to `app_name2`

```
"overrides": {
    "prod": {
      "producer": {
        "shards": 2,
        "subscriptions": [
          {
            "name": "app_name2_{{ ENVIRONMENT }}_consumer",
            "account_id": "123456789012",
            "active": false
          }
        ]
      }
  }
```

The result will be:

```
{ shards: 2,
  subscriptions:
   [ { name: 'app_name2_prod_consumer',
       account_id: '123456789012',
       active: false },
     { name: 'app_name2_prod_consumer',
       account_id: '987654321098',
       active: true } ],
  name: 'app_name_prod_producer',
  kms_key_alias: 'alias/app_name_prod_producer_key' }
```

There are two `app_name2` now.

Answer (score 3):

[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) seems to be exactly what you need.

Example:

```
var o1 = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}

var override = {
  a: 9
}

Object.assign(o1, override)
console.log(o1) // {a: 9, b: 2}
```

**EDIT**

Object.assign loops through only the root level.
For deep assignment you can use [lodash.defaultsDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#defaultsDeep):

```
var env = _.defaultsDeep(json.overrides.prod.producer, json.producer)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's what I am looking for.

Comment: I still need go through to each key and assign it. Otherwise, I will get less keys which is only in `overrides`.

Comment: Right, I had to give more details... Updated answer

Comment: Very very close. But when merge maps in list, it has to be one to one matched. I update in my original question

Comment: The `defaultsDeep` function overrides array elements by their position (try `_.defaultsDeep([{id: 1}], [{id:2}, {id:1}])`). If you want to compare and override array of objects using a specific key (i.e. `name`), lodash has a function for that: [unionBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#unionBy). You can override `subscriptions` first, using `unionBy`, then compare the entire configuration object